# Counting even and odd numbers in the columns of a triangular arrangement of the integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures

I write the positive numbers starting at $1$ in a triangle:$$\mathbb{N}_\triangle = \begin{matrix}
    &&&&&21&\ldots         \\
    &&&&15&20&\ldots       \\
    &&&10&14&19&\ldots     \\
    &&6&9&13&18&\ldots   \\
    &3&5&8&12&17&\ldots \\
    1&2&4&7&11&16&\ldots 
    \end{matrix}$$

I would like some help proving the following claim

> I denote the count of even numbers in column $n$ of
>   $\mathbb{N}_\triangle$ by $e(n)$. Then for $n>1$ $$e(n) = \Bigg\lfloor{n+2
>  \above 1.5pt 4}\Bigg\rfloor+\Bigg\lfloor{n+1
>  \above 1.5pt 4}\Bigg\rfloor$$ Note  the $n^{th}-column$ of $\mathbb{N}_\triangle$ has $n$ integers so I can set  $f(n)$ to count the number of odd integers in
>   $\mathbb{N}_\triangle$ and  $$f(n) = n-e(n)$$ It appears that 
>   $e(n)\in$ [A004524](https://oeis.org/A004524)

This is being driven by hunches and computer checks. $e(n)$ can be simplified but I think it is easier to remember it the way it is written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that each column forms an interval of integers, and so the numbers in the column alternate between being odd and even.

Hence if $n$ is even, so that there are an even number of integers in the $n$th column, exactly half of them will be even, so $e(2k) = k$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $n$ is odd, there will either be $\frac{n-1}{2}$ or $\frac{n+1}{2}$ even numbers, depending on whether the column starts with an odd or even number respectively.  Notice that the difference between the initial numbers of the $2k-1$st and $2k+1$st columns is $4k-1$, since the $2k-1$st column has $2k-1$ numbers, and the $2k$th column in between has a further $2k$ numbers.  As $4k-1$ is odd, that means that the initial numbers in the $2k-1$st and $2k+1$st odd columns have different parities.

Hence the first odd column starts with an odd number (namely $1$), the next odd column starts with an even number, the next odd column after that starts with an odd number again, and so on.  This means we have the formula

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccccccccc}
n & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 &  7 & 8 & ... & 4k + 1 & 4k + 2 & 4k + 3 & 4k + 4 & ... \\ \hline
e(n) & \frac{n-1}{2} & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n+1}{2} & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n-1}{2} & \frac{n}{2} & \frac{n+1}{2} & \frac{n}{2} & ... & 2k & 2k + 1 & 2k + 2 & 2k + 2 & ... \\
e(n) - \frac{n}{2} & - \frac12 & 0 & \frac12 & 0 & - \frac12 & 0 & \frac12 & 0 & ... & - \frac12 & 0 & \frac12 & 0 & ...
\end{array}. $$

As you can see, $e(n) - \frac{n}{2}$ is periodic with period $4$, as explained by the dependence on the parity of $n$, and then the alternating behaviour in the odd case.  Your formula captures this periodicity, and is correct.  Other ways to express it, which I find delightfully ridiculous, include
$$ e(n) = \frac12 \operatorname{Re} \left( n + i^{n+1} \right) = \frac12 \left( n - \sin \left(\frac12 n \pi\right)\right). $$

Comment: $Re$ for the real part?

Comment: Yep, that ignores the additive part when $n$ is even.  I've added another purely real solution, but that's a little less fun.

Comment: The motivation here are the sums $$\epsilon_s =\sum_{n \leq s}e(n)$$  Those sums can be written using the Riemann Zeta function evaluated at ${1 \above 1.5 pt 2}$.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: sounds interesting - you might like to add the motivation to the question, as people might not see it buried in the comments here.  Of course, that gives the formula $e(n) = \epsilon_n - \epsilon_{n-1}$, but I presume that is not a computationally friendly expression.

Comment: I don't want to go crazy in the comments but I am certain that $$\epsilon_s = 1,3,5,7,10,14,18,22,27,33,39,45,52,60,68,76,85,95,\ldots$$ and that $\epsilon_s$ appears to be the sequence [A054040](https://oeis.org/A054040) and a formula  claims that $$\epsilon_s ={1 \above 1.5pt 4}(s^2-2\zeta(2^{-1})s)+O(1)$$ I will edit the question later and bring in more motivation and details.

Comment: How did you deduce the formula $$e(n) ={1 \above 1.5pt 2}(n-sin({1 \above 1.5pt 2}(n\pi))$$ ?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez $\frac12 n$ is the base rate of growth of the function.  $e(n)$ then oscillates around this linear function periodically: as the table shows, $e(n) - \frac12 n$ has a period of $4$, alternating between $0$, $- \frac12$, $0$, $\frac12$.
On the other hand, $\sin x$ has a period of $2 \pi$, taking the values $0, 1, 0, -1$ at $x = 0, \frac12 \pi, \pi, \frac32 \pi$ respectively.  A simple rescaling then matches those two waves to each other.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez The earlier formula came in a similar way.  $i$ has order $4$, since $i^4 = 1$, and so I could use powers of $i$ to capture the behaviour of $e(n) - \frac12 n$.  Since the powers of $i$ alternate between being real and imaginary, taking the real part allowed me to make every other term equal to $0$, as needed.